# Execute SQL Insert statement into Azure SQL from a file

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have a file with more than 300,000 INSERT command lines.
I can use SSMS to copy some of those lines to insert my data, but I'm wasting my time loading my data by a group of 10,000 rows.

Can I execute all the Insert commands in my text file to my SQL Azure Database?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a script like below:

```
IF  OBJECT_ID('Sample_SalesTable', 'U') IS  NULL
BEGIN
CREATE  TABLE Sample_SalesTable (
Column1 NVARCHAR(50),
Column2 INT,
Column3 DECIMAL(10, 2)
);
END
INSERT  INTO SalesTable (Column1, Column2, Column3)
VALUES
('Value 1', 1, 1.23),
('Value 2', 2, 2.46),
('Value 3', 3, 3.69),
('Value 4', 4, 4.92),
('Value 5', 5, 6.15),
('Value 6', 6, 7.38),
('Value 7', 7, 8.61),
('Value 8', 8, 9.84),
('Value 9', 9, 11.07),
('Value 10', 10, 12.30),
SET  NOCOUNT  ON
BEGIN TRANSACTION
COMMIT
SET  NOCOUNT  OFF
```

- The **SET NOCOUNT ON** statement is used to improve performance When
  it is set to **'ON'** the server stops returning the number of rows
  affected by each statement as part of the result set.
- **BEGIN TRANSACTION** statement marks the start of a transaction. Transactions are used to group a set of SQL statements together
- The **COMMIT** statement is used to commit a transaction. When a
  transaction is committed, all the changes made by the transaction are
  made permanent and become visible to other users or processes
  accessing the data.
- After the transaction is committed, the script sets **NOCOUNT** back
  to '**OFF**' using the **SET NOCOUNT** **OFF** statement.

However, Inserting 300,000 rows using the same script can be time-consuming and may not be the most efficient approach.

As you are using the Azure Sql database one option is to use the **BULK INSERT** statement

If you can Prepare a CSV file that consist the data of the table you can easily insert the data using the below code.

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD ='test1223$'

CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL blobcred
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE externaldatasource
WITH(
   TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
   LOCATION = 'https://gen2june27.blob.core.windows.net',
   CREDENTIAL = blobcred
   )
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SalesTable02]
(
    ID INT ,
    Column1 VARCHAR(50),
    Column2 INT,
    Column3 DECIMAL(10,2)
)
BULK INSERT salesTable02 FROM 
'folder1/salesallrowsupdated.csv'
WITH (DATA_SOURCE = 'externaldatasource', FIRSTROW =2 ,FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR ='\n')
```

In order to execute the you will need to upload the CSV file which will consist of data to ADLS gen2

For example:

1. I have uploaded a CSV file to ADLS Gen 2. This CSV file have 50,000
   records.
   [image]

[image]

2. CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE while you are using this command you will need the SAS token you will find the SAS token in storage account it self.
   [image]
   When you are on the Shared access Signature page you will see
   Allowed resource types as unchecked. Check them like the above image and scroll down you will see **GENERATE SAS** Token
   [image]

Once you click the button you wll see the below
[image]
The SAS token looks something like this
**?sv=2022-11-02..........** from this token remove the first **'?'** and save rest of the token in a notepad.
And replace
***CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL blobcred WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE', SECRET = 'xxxxxxxYOURSASTOKENxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'***

3. When you are creating the CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE You need to
   replace this with your storage account name
   'https://yourstorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net'

Here is the **BULK INSERT** statement  utility to load the data from a file directly into the table. This method is generally faster and more efficient for large data sets.
***BULK INSERT salesTable02 FROM
'folder1/salesallrowsupdated.csv'
WITH (DATA_SOURCE = 'externaldatasource', FIRSTROW =2 ,FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR ='\n')***
I have used the same code to load 50,000 records into AZURE SQL database.

[image]

This above approach is more efficient for larger dataset and fast even for records more that 3,00,000.

Comment: @Frederic Le Guen Using the BULK INSERT can be the fastest way to insert all rows into the SQL table at time

Comment: Thanks for your message. I have found another way with Data Factory of Azure to load an Excel document to my database.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use [SQLCMD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver16) command prompt tool for that purpose:

```
sqlcmd -S tcp:myServer.database.windows.net -d database -U username -P password -i C:\<your file here>.sql
```

You may want to try the [new standalone version](https://github.com/microsoft/go-sqlcmd) based on GO language or used the version installed by SQL Server or installed by downloading first the [Command Line Utilities](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53591).